# Drupal 7 WYSIWYG not displaying for people with nodeaccess edit permission

Tags: drupal, wysiwyg

I have a Drupal 7 instal. So people can edit certain pages, we installed the nodeaccess module. This allows us to grant view, edit, and delete permission on a none-by-node basis.

We are having an issue where someone who has been granted editing permission this way does not get the WYSIWYG Editor textarea, just a plain textarea with the html.

I have permissions set so people who are logged in can use the WYSIWYG Filter, and I have also tried adjusting the module's weight to the up and down extremes, and no results.

Comment: Have you given all users access to at least the Filtered HTML text format? If they only have access to the Plain format, they won't see the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Found one solution for this problem. For people who are logged in, we gave them permission to do page editing with the admin theme. This works to get them the WYSIWYG textarea, but would like to put them back to doing the editing in the site's them.

Comment: People who are logged in have permission to use Plain Text, Filtered HTML, Full HTML, and CKEditor.